# Can a read-only /tmp result in "Unknown table engine 'InnoDB'"?

Tags: mysql, readonly

Can a read-only **/tmp** result in the error message "Unknown table engine 'InnoDB'"? (The MySQL error message doesn't mention anything about **/tmp**.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if your **/tmp** ends up read-only by accident (and yes, that can happen) then MySQL cannot use InnoDB tables. The end-user error message is "Unknown table engine 'InnoDB'", which is correct as far as it goes but does not tell you what is the underlying cause of the problem. A better error message might be something like, "Cannot use InnoDB table engine because MySQL cannot use a read-only /tmp".